# Toyota Camry 2004 service

Tags: toyota, old-cars, service

I have just bought a 2004 Toyota Corolla (Altise). I couldn't get the exact date of the last service but the guy said that the next service should be done in 3000km. I guess there is a standard set of things which are going to be checked during the upcoming service. Any idea where such list could be found? Also I'd like to know what is the advised frequency of services? This is my first car and I have only owned bikes until now. I know that I had to service my bike every 3000km but the service was different each time, for example:

```
3000 - small service (only check and clean filters and change oil)
6000 - medium service (change air filter, change oil)
9000 - small service (again)
12000 - full service (oil, belt, air filter)
goes again ...
```

These service points were defined by factory booklet I had with my bike. So just to summarize, I want to know where can I get the official information about services frequency and the list of what should be done during each service.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the owner's manual for maintenance and service schedules.  If you don't have the manual go here: http://www.toyota.com/owners/web/pages/resources/owners-manuals put in your car and check out the manual.

Also you can go here: http://smg.toyotapartsandservice.com/guides.php and put in your car, year and which mileage you are currently at and it will tell you exactly what needs service.